# Move process to a different tmux server

Tags: tmux

I use `tmux` via `ssh` on a shared machine and do all my work on one single tmux session. However, the shared machine has a per-process time limit policy and will kill processes if the time limit is exceeded. The `tmux` server don't take much CPU time, but after about one month it reaches the limit and the process is killed (also killing all the subprocesses I launched).

Knowing this, I can keep an eye on the process time and start another server before the limit is reached. But I was wondering if there was a way to change the "ownership" of an already running process ("reparent" a process to the new server instance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no portable way to do this. There is a program https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr that can do this on Linux (it uses ptrace and interposes all the system calls), but I don't know how reliable it is or if it is still maintained. YMMV.